# Google analytics Goal URL destenation?

Tags: google-analytics

I have to set a goal after user successfully signed up 
I don't send user to "successful signup page.html" , User returns to dashboard , I read that GA can read Parameters in URL, but does it read fragments ?
as I use fragments on my website can I use (/dashboard#Success) as my destination to count success goal ? 
or only parameters that can be red (/dashboard.html?signup=success)

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics, as you've already pointed out, disregards fragments, but you can still override the default URL to include the fragment in your page views so that your goals will still work:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'page': document.location.pathname  + '#' + document.location.hash})
```